# Joomla: What's the Object to get value from current content, if Registered only?

Tags: joomla

I need to know if the content being displayed to the user, is for registered only, not public. I think I can't do this trough JDocument or Mainframe, etc. I'm trying to figure this out. Any help on this subject?

Thanks for your attention,

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to load the article from the database. JDocument and the Application Mainframe objects control Joomla as a whole, while the article is managed by a component within Joomla.

If you're ultimately trying to modify the article before it's displayed, you can write a Content plugin, which will automatically have the article loaded. If you're trying to do something elsewhere, you'll need to detect when someone is viewing an article, extract the article id, then load the article from the database.